# Add a custom key shortcut within Javascript in Confluence

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, confluence

On my work we use Confluence. I need shortcut for monospace formatting on an edit page. 
Native shortcut is CTRL+SHIFT+M. It's taken in Opera by MyFlow feature and cannot be changed.

Is there an option to make it by using Javascript code?
 (I can make JS injection in a browser extension.)

Regular JS code for shortcuts which works fine but *not* on a confluence edit page:

```
// define a handler
function monospaceKeyTrigger(e) {

    // this would test for whichever key is 40 and the ctrl key at the same time
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 90) {
        // trigger click on monospace button
        //document.getElementById("rte-monospace").click();
        alert('!!monospace!!');
    }
}
// register the handler 
document.addEventListener('keyup', monospaceKeyTrigger, false);
```

So, what I've missed?
I guess, it's not triggering at all due to editor JS functionality...
Any advice guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found.

```js
//Set CTRL+SHIFT+L shortcut for monospace formatting in the editor
window.AJS.Rte.getEditor().shortcuts.add("ctrl+shift+l","monospace","confMonospace");
```

Cheers

P.S.
Thanks for this posts:

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35383/shortcut-key-for-monospaced-character-format-in-confluence (outdated, but helped to understand how to pass arguments)
- https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/37330905/ #47, take a look shortcuts list in `Confluence.KeyboardShortcuts`

P.P.S. Browser-ready Javascript code (tested in Atlassian Confluence 6.15.2)

Simple :

```js
// Set monospace formatting for a key shortcut in confluence
// Use a browser extension for injecting this code snippet
(function () {
    window.AJS.Rte.getEditor().shortcuts.add(
                'ctrl+shift+l',
                "monospace",
                "confMonospace"
            );
}());
```

Overprotected  :

```js
// Set monospace formatting for a key shortcut in confluence
// Use a browser extension for injecting this code snippet
console.log('include CJS');

let confKeyAdd = {
run: function () {
    this.key = {
        keyCode: 'ctrl+shift+l',
        codeType: 'monospace',
        codeConfType: 'confMonospace'
    };

    this.setKey();
},

waiter: function (shouldWaitCall, successCall, repeat = 10, interval = 1000) {
    let timerId;
    //wait here
    timerId = setInterval(
        function () {
            if (--repeat < 0) {
                console.log('confKeyAdd: Have not found an object.');
                clearTimeout(timerId);
                return;
            }

            if (shouldWaitCall()) {
                console.log('confKeyAdd: Still waiting... [' + repeat + ']');
                return;
            }

            clearTimeout(timerId);

            // call me!
            successCall();
        },
        interval
    );
},

setKey() {
    let _this = this;
    
    // first call: should-wait
    // second call: success
    this.waiter(
        function () {
            console.log('confKeyAdd: Checking...');
            return typeof window.AJS === 'undefined'
                || window.AJS.Rte.getEditor() === null
                || !window.AJS.Rte.getEditor().shortcuts;
        },
        function () {
            console.log('confKeyAdd: Adding a key shortcut for: ' + _this.key.keyCode);
            window.AJS.Rte.getEditor().shortcuts.add(
                _this.key.keyCode,
                _this.key.codeType,
                _this.key.codeConfType
            );
        },
    );
}
};

confKeyAdd.run();
```